# How does YUI tell web inspector / dev tools the type of an object?

Tags: javascript, webkit, yui

So I recently noticed that when I console.log a YUI node and inspect its _node attribute, that object has fields like "childNodes: NodeList" where NodeList is just a JS object. How does YUI provide meta-information so that web inspector knows that this object is actually a NodeList?

It may be extremely useful for debugging to be able to provide meta type information for object blobs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no meta-data.  NodeList is the name of the class, and debuggers can see what class every object belongs to.  In your example, somewhere a NodeList was created by calling

```
new NodeList();
```

and the engine remembers that type information.